# VLC ActiveX object crash on HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, vlc

I use VLC plugin to play audio/video files on web browser. It is working fine with HTTP, but the plugin crashes with HTTPS.
I work with MVC3 architecture and use controller for getting file stream. This file stream binds on view page with VLC plugin for playing video.

---

```
var fileName = "test.mp3";
            var filePathA = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("GetMediaFileStream", new { fileName = "mediafilename", id = "@Model.Id" }))";
            filePathA = filePathA.replace("mediafilename", fileName);
            var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
                    var options = new Array(":rtsp-tcp");
                    var id = vlc.playlist.add(filePathA, null, options);
                    vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
                    vlc.playlist.play();
```

---

and In controller

```
   public ActionResult GetMediaFileStream(int id)
        {
// code for sending stream to vlc plugin as;
         Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         Response.Flush();
        }
```

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptif about the crash? You got some error message or something? Also showing your code might also help.

Comment: Yeah thanks for reply
exactly method in controller not calling in HTTPS even it working fine with HTTP.

Comment: When I trace by fiddler I get error as
Session #118: The remote server (localhost) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors.